# Enthought Canopy does not create .pyc file

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I am using Canopy Version: 1.4.1 (64 bit) on a Windows 7.

I have two files `A.py` and `B.py`. `A.py` contains some modules and `B.py` imports one of `A.py`'s modules. When I change something on `A.py` and then run `B.py` a new compiled `A.py` (`A.pyc`) should be created but this is not the case when using the canopy IDE.

However a `A.py` does get compiled after restarting the kernel (Ctrl+.).

Is there a way to recompile `A.py` without having to restart the kernel?

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Canopy per se. It is how Python works in general. Once a module is loaded, it is not reloaded/recompiled if you change it. This can be avoided with `reload` as suggested in one of the other answers. There were different attempts in the past at having auto-reload mechanism but none of them were particularly robust, causing more troubles than what they solve.

The caching behaviour will happen in any Python session (Canopy, IPython frontends like the notebook, console, etc., a regular python shell, a server process, ...).

There are others ways to workaround the problem. In IPython and Canopy, you can use the `!python` command to execute your code as if you were on the shell.

Comment: Related, see https://support.enthought.com/entries/51912064-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart

Comment: Before posting I had tested it in the command line. As I had expected changes in `A.py` did get picked when running `B.py`. 
But now I get it, I wasn't thinking about Python session. with `!python` was enough for a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On python 2 you can reload the module:

```
reload(A)
```

On python 3 you need to import reload:

```
from importlib import reload
reload(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fit the question, but you also can use:

> python -m compileall .

from a command line pointed to your modules dir.

Comment: That also works and it is more convenient when you do not mind compiling everything. Thanks!